# JQUERY Two Clicks Issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery

I'm currently having some issues with my menu, its pretty basic as per the requirements.

**ISSUE:**

A user can click on the menu button once and open the sub menu, the user then clicks on the next button opening that sub menu, this is repeated as per the number of menu options. Once the user has clicked through them, if the user were to click another menu button once, it will not open, if the user clicks it a second time it will open. So after one run through the menu will only respond to two user clicks rather than a single one. This problem is occuring in other areas.

I suspect its something to do with my click handlers and event bubbling but my JQuery knowledge is self taught so I could do with a couple of pointers:

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu span').hide();
$('#menu li').not('.sub_menu').toggle(function(){
    //$('#menu span').hide();
    $('.open').hide();
    //$(this).next().not('#mm_choice, .sub_menu').show();
    $(this).nextUntil('li').not('#mm_choice, .sub_menu').show().addClass('open');
    }, function(){
    //$(this).next().not('#mm_choice, .sub_menu').hide();
    //$(this).nextUntil('li').not('#mm_choice, .sub_menu').hide().removeClass('open');
    $('.open').removeClass('open').hide();
        });
});
```

**HTML SOURCE CODE**

```
<div id="menu" title="Main Menu">
<ul id="m_choices" class="main_menu">

<li id="mm_choice" title="Customer Segmentation Menu">Customer Segmentation</li>

    <span id="c_seg"><li class="sub_menu" title="Cust Seg Menu1">Cust Seg Menu1</li><li id="c_seg" class="sub_menu" title="Cust Seg Menu2">Cust Seg Menu2</li><li id="c_seg" class="sub_menu" title="Cust Seg Menu3">Cust Seg Menu3</li></span>

<li id="mm_choice" title="Industry Menu">Industry Selection</li>

    <span id="all_ind"><li class="sub_menu" title="View All Industries">View All</li></span>

    <span id="spec_ind"><li class="sub_menu" title="View information on a specific Industry">View Specific Industry</li></span>

<li id="mm_choice" title="Customer Satisfaction Menu">Customer Satisfaction</li>

    <span id="all_cs"><li class="sub_menu" title="View every industry's CS survey results">View All</li></span>

    <span id="spec_cs"><li class="sub_menu" title="View a specific industry's CS survey results">View Specific Industry</li></span>

<li id="mm_choice" title="Performance Measures Menu">Performance Measures</li>

    <span id="all_pm"><li class="sub_menu" title="Trend Menu">View All</li></span>

    <span id="spec_pm"><li class="sub_menu" title="Trend Menu">View Specific Industry</li></span>

<li id="mm_choice" title="Business Performance Menu">Business Performance</li>

    <span id="all_bp"><li class="sub_menu" title="Bus Perf Menu">View All</li></span>

    <span id="spec_bp"><li class="sub_menu" title="Bus Perf Menu">View Specific Industry</li></span>

<li id="mm_choice" title="Trend Analysis Menu">Trend Analysis Menu</li>

    <span id="all_trends"><li class="sub_menu" title="Trend Menu">View All</li></span>

    <span id="spec_trends"><li class="sub_menu" title="Trend Menu">View Specific Industry Trends</li></span>  
</ul>
</div>
```

The menu.php file (html mark up) is imported (using php include();) into the index.php file. The JQuery file is imported in declerations.php, imported into index.php in the header. Declerations.php contains all necessary JQuery libraries. Intention is to add UI animation at a later stage so the .show() and .hide() methods will be elaborated upon.

Comment: Can you post this to jsfiddle and share the link?

Comment: You haven't posted any of your click handlers, and this is where the problem is likely to be.

Comment: the toggle function would be the click handler but as I mentioned below is also probably the cause

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a toggle for the menu I would suggest using the .click() method. The click would let you control what happens a little easier. Toggle() is great when you want to have two different states on a click but for a complex menu it may not be the best method.

Also you are wrapping your secondary navigation in span tags and the individual elements inside list-items. This is invalid HTML markup and will cause rendering issues in certain browsers. I would suggest changing those spans to ul's